# Laravel mysql query translation

Tags: laravel, translation

I need help translating this to Laravel. Thanks.

```
SELECT * FROM benefit 
WHERE id 
NOT IN ( 
       SELECT benefit_id 
       FROM benefit_aquired 
       WHERE benefit_aquired.user_id = 6 
       )
```

Comment: What have you tried? I could write this using Laravels query builder for you but it wouldn't help you learn.

Comment: I've been trying with joins and whereNotIn, but I think my syntax is wrong:

$result = DB::table('benefit')
       
 ->join('benefit_aquired', 
        function($join )
        {
            $join->on('benefit.id', '=', 'benefit_aquired.benefit_id');
             
  $query->whereNotIn( DB::raw('(benefit_aquired.benefit_id)'), function($query)
{
    $query->select('benefit_aquired.benefit_id')
      ->from('benefit_aquired')
      ->where('benefit_aquired.user_id', '=', 6);
});
        })
  
      
       ->get();
return $result;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you call it on `Benefit` model:

```
Benefit::whereNotIn('id', function ($q) use ($userId) {
  $q->from('benefit_acquired')
     ->where('user_id', $userId)
     ->select('benefit_id');
})->get();
```

This will give you exactly the same query you pasted.

For non-eloquent query it's just the same:

```
DB::table('benefit')->whereNotIn('id', function ($q) use ($userId) {
  $q->from('benefit_acquired')
     ->where('user_id', $userId)
     ->select('benefit_id');
})->get();
```

Comment: I'm sure this would work, but i'm not calling from Benefit model, I'm using inside a public function like this: 

public function noAdquiridoUser($id_user)
 {
     $result = DB::table('benefit') ...
}

Comment: Thanks!
 I tried it just before you updated, and it worked, but I still cannot concatenate the result with my models:

return $this->with('resource');

I need that array into my result, any ideas?

Comment: That's correct. You cannot use `with` on `Query\Builder`, for it is `Eloquent\Builder` method and works only on the model queries. Why you want to call `DB::table...` anyway?

Comment: I figured out, I was inserting the whereNotIn in the join not at the end. Thanks to everyone, specially to @jarek-tkaczyk

Answer (score -1):

If a query is too hard to translate to Laravel you can always use DB::SELECT. For example in one of my models I have a method like this:

```
 /**
* Get all predictions spent so far
* @param int $userId
* @return string
*/
public function getAllSpentPredictions($userId)
{
return DB::select("SELECT `predictions`.name , sum(ex.expenseValue) as value
FROM `predictions`
INNER JOIN (SELECT prediction_id, sum(value) as expenseValue from expenses GROUP BY prediction_id) ex
ON `predictions`.id = ex.prediction_id
WHERE `predictions` .tablet_id in (select id from tablets where user_id = $userId)
group by name
ORDER BY value DESC
;");
}
```

As you can see my SQL query was also a little bit complex, so I just used DB::select.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use BD::select, because I have some classes and models that I use for the result and I don't know how to combine them with DB::select.
I use something like this:
return $this->('resource');
I need the resource array in the results :(